# C++ Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)

Tags: c++, компиляция, mingw, clion, segmentation-fault

Переустанавливал Clion и начала появляться ошибка
`Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)` при выполнении такого кода:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    std::cout << "ASD";
}
```

При запуске debug, появляется segfault на строке `std::cout << "ASD";`
При этом код работает корректно, при использовании `printf` вместо `std::cout` :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    printf("ASD");
}
```

Использую bundled MinGW

Думаю что проблема с MinGW, но не уверен

Comment: `return 0;` вы не возвращаете код выхода... И в регистре может быть мусор, так что всегда возвращайте значение. Даже в main.